# How enable Dictionary encoding

Tags: java, apache-arrow

I'm newbie of Arrow and I'm using version 0.11.0 in java.

I created a simple junit test in which I use arrow-jdbc to create VectorSchemaRoot.
Now I'm trying to figure out how I can enable the use of dictionary encoding.

May someone help me?

Kind regards
Andrea

Comment: I recommend that you ask on the user@arrow.apache.org or dev@arrow.apache.org mailing list